# jQuery counter, counting down after reaching the number

Tags: jquery, counter

I'm using a jQuery code for showing animated stats for my web page.

The number animates successfully, but a few seconds after reaching its max value it starts counting down back to 1! How can I fix this?

```js
// Checks if any particular element is in viewport
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  return elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

// Animate numbers when scrolled into view
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var counters_triggered = false;
  var $counter_animated = $('.stat-counters > .stat > .counter > span');

  if ($('.stat-counters').isInViewport() && !counters_triggered) {
    counters_triggered = true;

    $.each($counter_animated, function() {
      var $counter = $(this);
      $counter.prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $counter.text()
      }, {
        duration: 5000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function(now) {
          $counter.text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.padding { height: 1000px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Scroll down...
<div class="padding"></div>
<div class="stat-counters d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
  <div class="stat col-md-4 px-0">
    <div class="counter">
      <span>10</span>+
    </div>
    <span class="text">Years of Experience</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please make the code runnable, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because your logic to prevent the animation being triggered multiple times on scroll isn't quite correct, and is in fact queuing the event handler multiple times.

Your `isInViewport()` function needs to be called on each individual element, not the collection. As such the `if` condition should be inside the `$.each()`.

In addition you're using a single variable to manage state of all of the animatable elements. You can manage their state individually by using a `data` attribute on them individually.

With that said, try this:

```js
// Checks if any particular element is in viewport
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  return elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

// Animate numbers when scrolled into view
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.stat-counters > .stat > .counter > span').each((i, el) => {
    var $counter = $(el);
    if (!$counter.isInViewport() || $counter.data('animation-started'))
      return;

    $counter.data('animation-started', true).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
      Counter: $counter.text()
    }, {
      duration: 5000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function(now) {
        $counter.text(Math.ceil(now));
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.padding {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Scroll down...
<div class="padding"></div>
<div class="stat-counters d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
  <div class="stat col-md-4 px-0">
    <div class="counter">
      <span>10</span>+
    </div>
    <span class="text">Years of Experience</span>
  </div>
</div>
```